# Android client getting all the inputStreamReader at the deco from the server

Tags: android, inputstream

I'm asking for a little help here..

I made a Android app in order to get messages from a server. The app just have to show the server's messages and nothing else.
the thing is nothing is shown in the UI, all the messages are shown when I disconnect the server. 
It's frustrating because the app get the data's, just don't show them before the disconnection of the server.

Here is my code :

```
public class SlimpleTextClientActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    //Following is the IP address of the chat server. You can change this IP address according to your configuration.
    // I have localhost IP address for Android emulator.
    private String CHAT_SERVER_IP = "192.168.2.2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slimple_text_client);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ChatOperator chatOperator = new ChatOperator();
        chatOperator.execute();

    }

    /**
     * This AsyncTask create the connection with the server and initialize the
     * chat senders and receivers.
     */
    private class ChatOperator extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                client = new Socket(CHAT_SERVER_IP, 6666); // Creating the server socket.

                if (client != null) {
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Server has not bean started on port 4444.");
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Faild to connect server " + CHAT_SERVER_IP);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Faild to connect server " + CHAT_SERVER_IP);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Following method is executed at the end of doInBackground method.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Receiver receiver = new Receiver(); // Initialize chat receiver AsyncTask.
            receiver.execute();

        }

    }

    /**
     * This AsyncTask continuously reads the input buffer and show the chat
     * message if a message is availble.
     */
    private class Receiver extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private String message;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while (true) {
                try {

                    if (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                        message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        publishProgress(null);

                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            textView.append( message + "\n");
        }
     }
    }
```

Hope that someone have an idea because here... I don't x) 
Simon !

EDIT : 
So... I went to java to test my code (simplification with the System.out.println)

Here is my code :

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Socket client;

  InputStream is = null; 
  InputStreamReader isr = null;
  BufferedReader br = null;

  try{
      client = new Socket("192.168.2.2", 6666);

      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());

     // create new buffered reader
     br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

     int value=0;
     String monChar = null;
     String maChaine = null;
     //System.out.println(maChaine);

     // reads to the end of the stream 
     while((value = br.read()) != -1)
     { 

         // converts int to character
         char c = (char) value;
         maChaine = maChaine + c;
     }

  }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{

     // releases resources associated with the streams
     if(is!=null)
        is.close();
     if(isr!=null)
        isr.close();
     if(br!=null)
        br.close();
  }
 }
}
```

The thing is that I can't reach maChaine. 
This does the same thing that before : I only can reach my String when the server is disconected. 
If I put a "System.out.println(maChaine);" in my While it will print something at each rows and if I put it after it will only do something if the server is disconected.

Comment: The client tries to read lines. With readLine(). But the server does not send lines. Did you check if readLine() returns?

Comment: Mmmm.. try without if (bufferedReader.ready()).

Comment: I tried without  "if (bufferedReader.ready())" and it's not the problem.
I think the problem may come from the readLine() but I don't really understand how to use just  "read()".

Comment: It is better that your server uses writeLine().

Comment: I don't have access to the server. 
The server send datas between <STX>datas;datas;datas<ETX>

Comment: Is there a way to add the "\n" at the reception of a message ? 
Or maybe something else than .readLine() that doesn't care about the end char of the data ?

Comment: No that would be to late anyhow. But before i can give a hint i would like to know if  <STX>datas;datas;datas<ETX>  is all textual data.

Comment: It's an ASCII data frame.

Comment: Replace 'message = bufferedReader.readLine();' by 'message = readMyLine(bufferedReader);'. Ten implement readMyLine() by reading bytes one by one from the stream and adding to a string. Stop when the string .endsWith() <ETX>. Return the string.